# E-mail form won't send when using certain characters

Tags: php, actionscript-3

I have been on this for days and days, and am at the point that I have pulled out so many hairs that I now have just one hair left on my head. That hair is my last bit of pride. But seriously though, I have found dozens of answers but *none* seem to apply to my problem!

I have an e-mail form for a website I made. The site and form are made in Flash (AS3), the script for processing the e-mail is an external php file. The e-mail form **works just fine, *except* for when I use certain characters:**

- `%` is not shown in the e-mail, including any text directly behind it
- when a `&`, `<` or `>` is present, the form will say '*sending..*' but not go beyond that point; I don't receive any e-mail.
- All (or most at least) other characters like !@#$^*_+-=~` are no problem.

I have already made sure both AS3 and php codes have

- `"MIME-Version: 1.0; Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8"` is included in my sending *`if`* check in the php file;
- the textfields in AS3 are set to `htmlText` instead of just `text`.

---

**My scripts:**

*mail.php*

```
    if( $yourName == true ) {
        $sender = $fromEmail;
        $yourEmail = "myemail@example.com"; // Here i of course use my own email address
        $ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']; // This gets the user's ip Address

        $emailMsg = "Van: $sender\r\n" . 
                    "Name: $yourName\r" .
                    "Subject: $yourSubject\n\n" .
                    "$yourMsg\n\n\n\n" .
                    "------------------------------\r" .
                    "Sent from IP-address $ipAddress\r" .
                    "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
       # these are three (out of many) things I tried to work around the problem #          
        //$emailMsg = str_replace( '&', "&amp;", $emailMsg );
        //$emailMsg = htmlspecialchars($emailMsg, ENT_QUOTES);
        //$emailMsg = mysql_real_escape_string($emailMsg);

        $return = "From: $sender\r\n";

        if( mail($yourEmail, "$yourSubject", $emailMsg, $return, "MIME-Version: 1.0; Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8")) { 
            echo "sentStatus=yes";
        }
        else {
            echo "sentStatus=no";
        }
    }
?>
```

*FormScript.as*

```
package  {
    /*required imports*/

public class FormScript extends Sprite {
    /*here are the variable declarations*/

    public function FormScript() {
        sendbtn.buttonMode = true;
        sendbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, submit);
        resetbtn.buttonMode = true;
        resetbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, reset);
        urlRequest.method = URLRequestMethod.POST;

        /*here are are some positionings and addchilds*/

        function init():void {
             //Set all fields to empty
             yourName.htmlText = "";
             fromEmail.htmlText = "";
             yourSubject.htmlText = "";
             yourMsg.htmlText = "";
             valid.text = "";
        }

        function submit(e:MouseEvent):void {                

        //Check to see if any of the fields are empty
            if(yourName.htmlText == "" || fromEmail.htmlText == "" ||
                yourSubject.htmlText == "" ||yourMsg.htmlText == "" ) {
                valid.text = "All fields must be filled in";
            }//Check if you're using a valid email address

            else if(!checkEmail(fromEmail.htmlText)) {
                valid.text = "Please enter a valid e-mail address";
            } 

            else { 
                valid.text = "Sending..";

                var emailData:String = 
                "name=" + yourName.htmlText +
                "&from=" + fromEmail.htmlText +
                "&subject=" + yourSubject.htmlText +
                "&msg=" + yourMsg.htmlText;

                var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables(emailData);
                urlVars.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
                urlRequest.data = urlVars; varLoad.load( urlRequest );
                varLoad.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, thankYou );
            }
        }
        function reset(e:MouseEvent):void {
            init(); //call the initial clear function
        }
        function checkEmail(s:String):Boolean {
            //yourMsg.text = escape("&");

            //This tests for correct email address
            var p:RegExp = /(\w|[_.\-])+@((\w|-)+\.)+\w{2,4}+/;
            var r:Object = p.exec(s);
            if( r == null ) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        function thankYou(e:Event):void { 
            var loader:URLLoader = URLLoader(e.target); 
            var sent = new URLVariables(loader.data).sentStatus;
            //valid.text = sent;
            if( sent == "yes" ) {
                valid.text = "Thank you for your e-mail!"; timer = new Timer(500);
                timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, msgSent);
                timer.start();
            }
            else {
                valid.text = "Something went wrong, please try again";
            }
        }

        function msgSent(te:TimerEvent):void {
            if(timer.currentCount >= 10) {
                init();
                timer.removeEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, msgSent);
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

---

Keywords:ampersand special characters symbols less-than less than greater-than greater than   *please don't edit this, it's for others to find this question because you can't search for an '&' and such.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most obvious culprit here is messy way you're creating the emailData string.  As a first step I'd recommend reformatting it to the following:

```
var urlVars:URLVariables = new URLVariables();
urlVars.name = yourName.htmlText;
urlVars.from = fromEmail.htmlText;
urlVars.subject = yourSubject.htmlText;
urlVars.msg = yourMsg.htmlText;
```

I think this will automatically URI encode the values, but if not, use encodeURI() as suggested by Mark Knol.

Comment: Should I keep `urlVars.dataFormat = URLLoaderDataFormat.TEXT;
     urlRequest.data = urlVars; varLoad.load( urlRequest );` or replace this with your code?

Comment: @poepje Keep them, all the above code is doing is creating the urlVars in a bit more of a robust way than passing the emailData string.

Comment: I just tried and it worked, thanks a bunch. Received e-mails do make &amp; and such out of it, but I think I'll figure that out :)

Answer (score 1):

Within Flash, the values need to be encoded, otherwise the querystring could be corrupted.

```
var emailData:String = 
            "name=" + encodeURI(yourName.htmlText) +
            "&from=" + encodeURI(fromEmail.htmlText) +
            "&subject=" + encodeURI(yourSubject.htmlText) +
            "&msg=" + encodeURI(yourMsg.htmlText);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$emailMsg = utf8_decode($emailMsg);
```

I decode all my strings I get from Flash.

If this doesn't help, use

```
$emailMsg = urldecode($emailMsg);
```

Or both :D